# Passing 'this' from view to viewmodel

Tags: wpf, xaml, this

I have a button which, when clicked, should open a new window as a modal window. I was thinking of passing `this` from xaml and in the viewmodel, would have got the parentwindow as `Window.GetWindow(parameter)`. Is there any equivalent to `this` in xaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are in a disconnected context you can pass the window using a `RelativeSource` binding with `AncestorType=Window`.

Comment: While this would work fine, I do hope future readers do not take this approach to pass UI elements to VM's in MVVM and then use the incoming object as `System.Windows.Window` in the VM. There are quite a few alternative to using a "messenger" pattern or even implement an interface and use the incoming object as a type of that interface to keep the VM and View disconnected to allow unit-testing